# Is it safe to use a laptop in an ESD safe environment?

Tags: esd, laptop

I work in a highly sensitive ESD environment. I have equipment worth tens of thousands of dollars that can be damaged with a single zap.

For testing purpose, I need to get my laptop inside this ESD environment. The laptop is an ASUS TUF FX505 with 3-pin charger always connected to plug outlet.

Is it OK to use the laptop inside the ESD environment or will it cause ESD problems that I am unable to foresee? (Damaging the laptop due to ESD is not priority here, but the protection of rest of the electronics in the ESD setup is of high priority.)

Comment: It seems that if your company maintains such an environment to protect their equipment there would be some ESD experts on-staff to assist in ensuring that any changes to the environment are done is an ESD-safe manner.  Why not consult your local experts instead of some random people on the internet?

Comment: True that. We will require training from the local vendors about ESD handling soon.

Answer (score 2):

Electronic equipment generally doesn't produce an electrostatic charge. Laptops are generally insulated from the outside, so the chassis might hold some charge, but if you are in an ESD controlled environment, that charge will dissipate either through the desk, ESD mat, Earth or the moisture in the air.

Your own movement and friction (cloths, environment) generates much more electrostatic energy.